# Is it possible to write a sql query that is grouped based on a running total of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

It would be easier to explain with an example. Suppose I wanted to get at most 5 items per group.

My input would be a table looking like this:

```
Item    Count
A        2
A        3
A        3
B        4
B        4
B        5
C        1
```

And my desired output would look like this:

```
Item     Count
A        5
A>5      3
B        4
B>5      9
C        1
```

An alternative output that I could also work with would be

```
Item    Count    RunningTotal
A       2        2
A       3        5
A       3        8
B       4        4
B       4        8
B       5        13
C       1        1
```

I can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the top X records in each group, however my requirement is to get the top X items for each group, not X records. My mind is drawing a blank as to how to do this.

Comment: What query do you have so far..?

Comment: An important thing for running total questions is to find out how are your items ordered. Would it be correct to assume that they are ordered by ID, or do you have another column (e.g. a date) on which the data is ordered?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight They are ordered by the user who created the record first (some users have higher priority then others), than by the date the record was created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @yourTable table (item char(1), [count] int)

insert into @yourTable
select 'A', 2 union all
select 'A', 3 union all
select 'A', 3 union all
select 'B', 4 union all
select 'B', 4 union all
select 'B', 5 union all
select 'C', 1

;with cte(item, count, row) as (
    select *, row_number() over ( partition by item order by item, [count]) 
    from @yourTable
)
select t1.Item, t1.Count, sum(t2.count) as RunningTotal from cte t1
join cte t2 on t1.item = t2.item and t2.row <= t1.row
group by t1.item, t1.count, t1.row
```

Result:

```
Item Count       RunningTotal
---- ----------- ------------
A    2           2
A    3           5
A    3           8
B    4           4
B    4           8
B    5           13
C    1           1
```

Comment: ow my head. My query is quite a bit more complex than the example in my question, and trying to wrap my head around combining that with your code sample was interesting. Thank you so much though, this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the clarifications from your comment, you should be able to produce the second kid of output from your post by running this query:

```
select t.Item
,   t.Count
,   (select sum(tt.count)
    from mytable tt
    where t.item=tt.item and (tt.creating_user_priority < t.creating_user_priority or
        ( tt.creating_user_priority = t.creating_user_priority and tt.created_date < t.createdDate))
    ) as RunningTotal
from mytable t
```

Comment: +1 for the right idea, although I accepted Michal's answer because the join is better on performance than a subquery. Thanks :)

Comment: @Rachel These days, query optimizers of non-toy RDBMS engines, such as SQL Server's, reliably come up with identical execution plans for joins and correlated subqueries when they are semantically identical to each other. I always start with a query that expresses my intentions more directly, and only then optimize if the query analyzer tells me that it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @yourTable table (item char(1), [count] int)

insert into @yourTable
select 'A', 2 union all
select 'A', 3 union all
select 'A', 3 union all
select 'B', 4 union all
select 'B', 4 union all
select 'B', 5 union all
select 'C', 1

;with cte(item, count, row) as (
    select *, row_number() over ( partition by item order by item, [count]) 
    from @yourTable
)

select t1.row, t1.Item, t1.Count, sum(t2.count) as RunningTotal
into #RunTotal
from cte t1
join cte t2 on t1.item = t2.item and t2.row <= t1.row
group by t1.item, t1.count, t1.row


alter table #RunTotal
add GrandTotal int

update rt
set GrandTotal = gt.Total
from #RunTotal rt
left join ( 
    select Item, sum(Count) Total
    from #RunTotal rt
    group by Item) gt
on rt.Item = gt.Item


select Item, max(RunningTotal)
from #RunTotal
where RunningTotal <= 5
group by Item

union

select a.Item + '>5', total - five
from (
    select Item, max(GrandTotal) total
    from #RunTotal
    where GrandTotal > 5
    group by Item
) a
left join (
    select Item, max(RunningTotal) five
    from #RunTotal
    where RunningTotal <= 5
    group by Item
) b
    on a.Item = b.Item
```

I've updated the accepted answer and got your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Item, SUM(Count)
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY Item
HAVING SUM(Count) <=5 

UNION  

SELECT Item,  5
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY Item
HAVING SUM(Count) >5 

UNION  


SELECT t2.Item + '>5', Sum(t2.Count) - 5
FROM mytable t2
GOUP BY Item
HAVING SUM(Count) > 5

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: I need to be able to identify the actual rows that are in each group since they get processed one at a time, so this won't work. Also, the items need to be ordered in a specific way so that the high priority records are included in the top 5 group

Comment: @Rachel - "high priority records"? You do realize that this comment is the *first* place you've mentioned such a requirement? Edit your question. Add more details, more sample data, try to be clear on *all* of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'A' as Name, 2 as Cnt
into #tmp
union all select 'A',3
union all select 'A',3
union all select 'B',4
union all select 'B',4
union all select 'B',5
union all select 'C',1

select Name, case when sum(cnt) > 5 then 5 else sum(cnt) end Cnt
from #tmp
group by Name
union 
select Name+'>5', sum(cnt)-5 Cnt
from #tmp
group by Name
having sum(cnt) > 5
```

Here is what I have so far. I know it's not complete but... this should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I can get your second output by using a temp table and an update pass:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Value VARCHAR(5)
    ,Number INT
    ,Total INT
)
INSERT INTO @Data (Value, Number) VALUES ('A',2)
INSERT INTO @Data (Value, Number) VALUES ('A',3)
INSERT INTO @Data (Value, Number) VALUES ('A',3)
INSERT INTO @Data (Value, Number) VALUES ('B',4)
INSERT INTO @Data (Value, Number) VALUES ('B',4)
INSERT INTO @Data (Value, Number) VALUES ('B',5)
INSERT INTO @Data (Value, Number) VALUES ('C',1)

DECLARE 
    @Value VARCHAR(5)
    ,@Count INT

UPDATE @Data
SET
    @Count = Total = CASE WHEN Value = @Value THEN Number + @Count ELSE Number END
    ,@Value = Value
FROM @Data AS D

SELECT 
    Value
    ,Number
    ,Total 
FROM @Data
```

There may be better ways, but this should work.